# What is the difference between classes and test-classes

Tags: java, spring, maven, junit, logback

I had a springmvc maven project By IntelliJ Idea,I put the logbak.xml in the `src/main/resources` folder and another logbak.xml with different configurations in the `src/test/resources` folder.

When running my Junit Test,the logbak.xml in the test folder worked.
When running my web in tomcat server,the logbak.xml in the main folder worked.

If I had no logbak.xml in test folder,the logbak.xml in the main folder worked.

Why the logbak.xml can't be loaded twice?
How to decide which file can be loaded first when different running above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regular classes (`src/main/...`) can work stand-alone (without those in the test part). These are the classes that implement the actual work of of your program or library.
Hence if you package everything only the regular classes are included.

As you have observed the logback.xml from src/main will be used.

The test classes (`src/test/...`) are there to test the regular classes. Hence you need the test classes and the regular classes in the classpath (and the correspondent resources as well). 
The test classes are added to the classpath before the regular classes By Maven(IDE uses the information provided by Maven) - therefore classes/resource that exists in the test part have a higher priority. If a requested class/resource does not exists in the test part but in the main part then the one from the main part is loaded - just as you have observed.

Comment: tanks.I want to know who set up the priority? IntelliJ or maven?

Comment: You can try to manually define the source folders in the pom.xml. However  if you want a specific configuration do not create two logback.xml files of the same name - use a different name and set it via system property `logback.configurationFile` as logback configuration file - see https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#configFileProperty

Comment: Thanks,maybe my question was not clear.About your comment  "the test classes are added to the classpath before the regular classes". I was wondering which one make the test part have a higher priority,the IDE or the Maven. Either running test with IDE or maven commands,the test part will be added to classpath. Which dose add the test part to ? IDE or Maven

Comment: Who adds the test part to the classpath and sets the priority?  IDE? Maven? Or any other else?

Comment: Usually the IDE uses the information provided by maven. May be you can override it however that would destroy the advantage of maven that it does work without IDE.

Comment: I got it! May be the IDE has the default behavior to match the structure of maven such as dependencies and classes! Your opinion helps me figure it out! Thanks!